# What happens when I open a text file and it's equal to NULL?

Tags: c, file, text-files, fopen

We recently learned opening files in the uni and the prof didn't tell us this. So I open a text file and do a check whether the file is equal to NULL or not.
What if it is equal to NULL? It means that I have no data in the file?

```
FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Nops, it means that the file doesn't exists or you don't have permissions to read it ... use `perror("fopen");` to get more info.

Comment: Did you read `man fopen` (and `man errno`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if fopen() returns a NULL, it means that the file opening was not successfully accomplished, also in that case it sets the errno global variable is set to duplicate an error. You can also read 'man fopen' in your terminal for more details.